# Problme in Android

Tags: java, android-studio, version, java-11

While I was working on a project in Android Studio, I encountered a Java problem:

`Cause: com/github/gitofleonardo/simplesqlitebrowser/sqlite/SqliteFileType has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You are trying to use a class compiled for Java 17 (that `SqliteFileType` class) on a Java 11 JVM.  Either upgrade the JVM to Java 17 or recompile that class library for Java 11.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please give a descriptive headline, and use english also in the headline.
No one having a similar problem will ever find your question with this heading.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the code which you re trying to run is compiled in a more recent version of java(class file version 61.0) on a java runtime environment that only
recognizes class file versions up to 55.0.
So you should do:
check your java version if its old update ur java version & check dependencies.
I hope it gonna be OK lemme know if you fixed that problem.